# Why can't the Java == operator be used on two different Objects of non related types?

Tags: java

From what I understand, the == operator in java checks if two references point to the same object in memory. If that's the case, when I use it on two different Objects which are both instances of a different class, I should get false. I am confused as to why I am getting a compiler error from the following code:

```
public class HelloWorld{

    public static class A {}
    
    public static class B {}

     public static void main(String []args){
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();
        System.out.println(a == b);
     }
}
```

The error I get is:

```
HelloWorld.java:11: error: incomparable types: A and B
        System.out.println(a == b);
                             ^
1 error
```

If I convert one of them to an Object it runs and returns false. I just can't understand why I need to convert to an Object. Both classed are a type of Object, since all classes inherit Object anyhow.
Any help would be much appreciated, Michael.

EDIT: Thanks for the helpful comments, I would like to provide some context for my question. I am asking it after taking a test which had a similar question. It included several classes and one of the questions included several statements which could either run and produce an output or fail at runtime or compile time. One of them was about comparing two objects like in the example above. I thought that there is nothing wrong in doing that, you would get false, but that's not a problem. Of course in real life there is no reason to do that if you know the types before runtime, but since it was a test it seemed possible.

Comment: You can't compare an Apple to a Banana. But you can compare a Fruit to a Fruit. Object is the shared "parent class" of (nearly) every type i.e. the common ancestor of both `A` and `B` in your example, which is why they can be compared once you cast (either of them) them to object.

Comment: If it were permitted, it would always return false unless they're both null. That's almost *never* a useful thing to do - so the compiler is protecting you from making a comparison that is very unlikely to be what you *actually* want to do. This is a good thing.

Comment: They cannot possibly be `==`. So replace your condition with the expression `false`.

Comment: The compiler knows that `a` will never be equal to `b` due to different types. If you explicitly remove the type information by casting to `Object` the compiler will no longer know that but at runtime they will always be non-equal anyway.

Comment: @luk2302: Unless they're both null... (obviously they won't be in this case as they've been initialized to non-null values in the lines before, but more generally they could be)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you think about it, the example you have is completely redundant, you know without even running the code that those two objects can't possibly be comparable because they are of 2 different classes, the compiler is just saving you some time by saying their incomparable up front.

Comparing equality like this is only useful when you don't know what the type is upfront, or you know the type but they are of the same class. For example:

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static class A {}

    public static class B {}
    
    public static void compare(Object a, Object b) {
        boolean comparison = a == b;
        System.out.println(comparison);
    }

    public static void main(String []args) {
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();
        compare(a, b);
    }
}
```

Assume in this example that you only know about the compare method, then the equality method would make sense because you don't know the types in advance, they're just `Objects`.

Side note, when comparing objects like this, you're more then likely going to want to use the `.equals()` method, which allows you to compare object contents rather then reference.

Comment: If `B` extends `A`, `a` and `b` are different classes but can be compared with `==`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. See my edit above for some clarification.